# HSEARCH400655: Invalid cardinality for projection on field

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

We have 3 records as `ProjectionConstructor` to map the projections from ES backend

**Doctor.java**

```
public record Doctor(
    UUID id,
    String fullName,
    @ObjectProjection(includeDepth = 2) DoctorDetails doctorDetails,
    @ObjectProjection(includeDepth = 1) List<DoctorEspecialty> doctorEspecialties // **a Many To Many linking for `Especialties`
){}
```

**DoctorEspecialty.java**

```
@ProjectionConstructor
public record DoctorEspecialty(
    UUID id,
    @ObjectProjection(includeDepth = 1) Especialty especialtyCode,
    @ObjectProjection(includeDepth = 1) Doctor doctor) {}
```

**Especialty.java**

```
@ProjectionConstructor
public record Especialty(
    UUID id,
    String especialtyName,
    String localName
    Integer code,
    @ObjectProjection(includeDepth = 1) Language language) {}
```

We are using the below code to retrieve the `Doctor` data and use mapstruct to map the data, ex: `doctorMapper`:

```
List<**.projection.Doctor> doctors = searchSession
            .search(Doctor.class)
            .select(**.projection.Doctor.class)
            .where((f, root) -> {
                root.add(f.matchAll());
                root.add(
                    // dynamic criteria based on request
            })
            .fetchHits(pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize(), pageable.getPageSize());

        return new PageImpl<DoctorDTO>(doctors.stream().map(doctorMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList()), pageable, suppliers.size());
```

Getting below error:

- "status" : 500,
- "detail" : "HSEARCH400655: Invalid cardinality for
  projection on field 'doctorEspecialties.especialtyCode.id': the
  projection is single-valued, but this field is effectively
  multi-valued in this context, because parent object field
  'doctorEspecialties' is multi-valued. Either call '.multi()' when you
  create the projection on field
  'doctorEspecialties.especialtyCode.id', or wrap that projection in an
  object projection like this:
  'f.object("doctorEspecialties").from().as(...).multi()'.",

It works fine if we use a composite record, but that leads to
duplicate/redundent code in both projection-dtos and mapstruct
mappers.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you show me the relevant parts of your Doctor entity? What version of Hibernate Search are you using?

Comment: It would help considerably if you could create a reproducer based on this : https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/main/search/hibernate-search-6/orm-elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @yrodiere.
 Here is the environment details:
springBootVersion=3.1.5
hibernateVersion=6.2.9.Final
hibernate_search=6.2.2.Final
ES version: 8.7.1
JDK version: openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17

Let me work on building the testcase as requested, please be informed it may take some time...

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait. Unrelated to your question, but FWIW if you want to avoid redundant code, you could use your DTOs as projections directly, and get rid of the mapstruct step. At least for this specific example. That's what I did elsewhere, e.g. https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-demos/pull/113/files#diff-c74bd472cf116a947d5d959890d690405ea0c25cd54ba0fb79f81b55739ad707R122